# How do I install openSUSE 12.1 from an external hard disk?

Tags: opensuse, system-installation, usb-drive, bios

For some reason, my laptop (HP ProBook 5320m) refuses to boot when I install the ISO images for openSUSE 12.1 on an USB stick (the stick starts to blink and then the internal fan goes into overdrive and I have to switch off the laptop).

I also tried the NET version, different USB sticks, no game. Currently, openSUSE 11.4 is installed on the laptop, is it's not *impossible* to install. My guess is that something was changed in the 12.1 release which the BIOS of the laptop doesn't like.

So my last hope is to create a bootable external hard disk but when I look into the folder `/boot` of the ISO image, I can't find GRUB or anything that I recognize.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to replace the ISO boot loader with GRUB?
2. Is there some other way to install 12.1 on openSUSE 11.4? Ubuntu can do a dist upgrade in the running system, for example. Is something like that possible with openSUSE, too?
3. Could I boot with the installer for 11.4 and somehow make it use the installation files for 12.1?

PS: Dear HP engineers. Your BIOS looks great but I'd prefer one that works. Just saying :-(

Comment: here's how to upgrade opensuse 11.4 to 12.1: http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-upgrade-opensuse-11.4-to-12.1-desktop-and-server

Comment: @ysangkok: Please write this as an answer so I can comment or accept it (after testing it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Probably not. GRUB is a general purpose bootloader. The SYSLINUX bootloaders are different, there is [one for each medium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYSLINUX).
2. [How to upgrade OpenSuSE 11.4 to 12.1](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-upgrade-opensuse-11.4-to-12.1-desktop-and-server)

Comment: The second approach worked perfectly for me. I suggest to run `script /root/dup-12.1.log` before running `zypper dup`; that will log the output of `zypper` into the file `/root/dup-12.1.log` so you can check for errors at your leisure.